# Sun Java 6 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, sun, java-6, jpcap

The java library I need (jpcap) only works on Java 6, it won't work with Java 7. Is it still possible to install Java 6 on Ubuntu? According to the [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Choosing_the_default_Java_to_use):

> Oracle (Sun) Java 6 is no longer available to be distributed by Ubuntu, because of license issues

I've tried to use the instructions on the same site but they don't seem to work...
`./jre-6u34-linux-i586.bin` doesn't seem to do anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [these instructions](http://ddmytrenko.blogspot.de/2012/02/installing-sun-java-6-jdk-on-debian.html) on how to install Sun JDK 6. In older versions of the repositories the desired package is included.

---

If you're not obliged to, try using [`jNetPcap`](http://jnetpcap.com/) instead. It's another wrapper around pcap, it just works on more recent JVMs and is not restricted to 32 bit architecture.

Comment: Does jNetCap allow you to look at the packet data/payload? It's a part of the project I'm running

Comment: Another advantage is a better documentation of jNetPcap. Look at: [Chapter 3](http://jnetpcap.com/userguide/ch3): Packet decoding – 3.3 - Working with protocol headers – 3.4 - Formatting packets for text output

Comment: Just added jnetcap to my project there - very simple and easy, hopefully it works with my previous GUI code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would try the OpenJDK 6 which AFAIK is fine on Ubuntu and check you have the right version 32-bit vs 64-bit for your machine. `i586` is 32-bit and won't work with a 64-bit build of jpcap.

Comment: Does jpcap work with OpenJDK? There is a few different versions of jpcap, just to clarify I'm working with the one that used to be at netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/, until it went down,,, I have a 32-bit build of this jpcap so i would need a 32-bit OpenJDK 6 yes?

Comment: I'll try this so and if it doesn't work I'll try the jNetPcap - thanks